# Elasticsearch: Why my index query returns result which is not in my specific index

Tags: elasticsearch

From the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-query.html#query-dsl-indices-query):

> The indices query is useful in cases where a search is executed across multiple indices. It allows to specify a list of index names and an inner query that is only executed for indices matching names on that list.

So I just set index to `user_event-2017.04.18`, and I only want the result from that index, but it turns out Elasticsearch gives me some result of  `.kibana` index...

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use POST instead of GET?

Comment: And why not simply using POST `user_event-2017.04.18/_search` instead of searching on all indices and having to use the `indices` query to focus on a single index?

Comment: @Val Result remains the same after I changed the verb from GET to POST, note that in the document they use GET too.

Comment: Yeah I know but it's a bad practice. Always use POST when sending a body. Ok now what happens when sending `POST user_event-2017.04.18/_search`?

Comment: @Val It works, thanks for that, but I still wonder why I get that result by using index queries... Is that a bug?

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val It's 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 5.0.0, the `indices` query has been deprecated, you should run a `term` query on the `_index` field instead:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": {"_index": "user_event-2017.04.18"}},
        { "term": {"tag": "wow"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even better, simply run the query on the `user_event-2017.04.18` index directly

```
POST user_event-2017.04.18/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        { "term": {"tag": "wow"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```